reflect and blur image filter not working
hi my image filter does not work for reflect and blur please can you help me find the solution
the reflect function reflects the image horizontally
the blur function blurs the image
When i pass images into blur it seems to work but one half of the image is only showing on two sides with reflect
filter.c
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#include "helpers.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Define allowable filters
    char *filters = "bgrs";

    // Get filter flag and check validity
    char filter = getopt(argc, argv, filters);
    if (filter == '?')
    {
        printf("Invalid filter.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Ensure only one filter
    if (getopt(argc, argv, filters) != -1)
    {
        printf("Only one filter allowed.\n");
        return 2;
    }

    // Ensure proper usage
    if (argc != optind + 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./filter [flag] infile outfile\n");
        return 3;
    }

    // Remember filenames
    char *infile = argv[optind];
    char *outfile = argv[optind + 1];

    // Open input file
    FILE *inptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open %s.\n", infile);
        return 4;
    }

    // Open output file
    FILE *outptr = fopen(outfile, "w");
    if (outptr == NULL)
    {
        fclose(inptr);
        printf("Could not create %s.\n", outfile);
        return 5;
    }

    // Read infile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    BITMAPFILEHEADER bf;
    fread(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // Read infile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    BITMAPINFOHEADER bi;
    fread(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, inptr);

    // Ensure infile is (likely) a 24-bit uncompressed BMP 4.0
    if (bf.bfType != 0x4d42 || bf.bfOffBits != 54 || bi.biSize != 40 ||
        bi.biBitCount != 24 || bi.biCompression != 0)
    {
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        printf("Unsupported file format.\n");
        return 6;
    }

    // Get image's dimensions
    int height = abs(bi.biHeight);
    int width = bi.biWidth;

    // Allocate memory for image
    RGBTRIPLE(*image)[width] = calloc(height, width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE));
    if (image == NULL)
    {
        printf("Not enough memory to store image.\n");
        fclose(outptr);
        fclose(inptr);
        return 7;
    }

    // Determine padding for scanlines
    int padding = (4 - (width * sizeof(RGBTRIPLE)) % 4) % 4;

    // Iterate over infile's scanlines
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // Read row into pixel array
        fread(image[i], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), width, inptr);

        // Skip over padding
        fseek(inptr, padding, SEEK_CUR);
    }

    // Filter image
    switch (filter)
    {
        // Blur
        case 'b':
            blur(height, width, image);
            break;

        // Grayscale
        case 'g':
            grayscale(height, width, image);
            break;

        // Reflection
        case 'r':
            reflect(height, width, image);
            break;

        // Sepia
        case 's':
            sepia(height, width, image);
            break;
    }

    // Write outfile's BITMAPFILEHEADER
    fwrite(&bf, sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // Write outfile's BITMAPINFOHEADER
    fwrite(&bi, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER), 1, outptr);

    // Write new pixels to outfile
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        // Write row to outfile
        fwrite(image[i], sizeof(RGBTRIPLE), width, outptr);

        // Write padding at end of row
        for (int k = 0; k < padding; k++)
        {
            fputc(0x00, outptr);
        }
    }

    // Free memory for image
    free(image);

    // Close files
    fclose(inptr);
    fclose(outptr);
    return 0;
}

helpers.c
#include "helpers.h"
#include <math.h>

// Convert image to grayscale
void grayscale(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                float average = (image[i][j].rgbtRed + image[i][j].rgbtGreen + image[i][j]. rgbtBlue) / 3.0;
                average = round(average);
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = average;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = average;
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = average;
            }
    }
    return;
}

// Convert image to sepia
void sepia(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
            {
                int sepiaRed = round(0.393 * image[i][j].rgbtRed + 0.769 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen + 0.189 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue);
                int sepiaGreen = round(0.349 * image[i][j].rgbtRed + 0.686 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen + 0.168 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue);
                int sepiaBlue = round(0.272 * image[i][j].rgbtRed + 0.534 * image[i][j].rgbtGreen + 0.131 * image[i][j].rgbtBlue);
                if (sepiaRed > 255)
                {
                    sepiaRed = 255;
                }
                if (sepiaGreen > 255)
                {
                    sepiaGreen = 255;
                }
                if (sepiaBlue > 255)
                {
                    sepiaBlue = 255;
                }
                image[i][j].rgbtRed = sepiaRed;
                image[i][j].rgbtGreen = sepiaGreen;
                image[i][j].rgbtBlue = sepiaBlue;
            }
    }
    return;
}

// Reflect image horizontally
void reflect(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < floor(width / 2) + 1; j++)
        {
            RGBTRIPLE swap = image[i][j];
            image[i][j] = image[i][width-j];
            image[i][width-j] = swap;
        }
    }
    return;
}

// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    RGBTRIPLE copy[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }
    float totalRed;
    float totalGreen;
    float totalBlue;
    int count;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            count = 0;
            totalRed = 0;
            totalGreen = 0;
            totalBlue = 0;
            for (int k = -1; k < 2; k++)
            {
                for (int l = -1; l < 2; l++)
                {
                    if((i+k >= 0 && i+k < width) && (j+l >=0 && j+l < width))
                    {
                        totalRed += copy[i+k][j+l].rgbtRed;
                        totalGreen += copy[i+k][j+l].rgbtGreen;
                        totalBlue += copy[i+k][j+l].rgbtBlue;
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }
            image[i][j].rgbtRed = totalRed / count;
            image[i][j].rgbtGreen = totalGreen / count;
            image[i][j].rgbtBlue = totalBlue / count;
        }
    }
    return;
}


ran a cs50 check50 test but it has the following output
check50
cs50/problems/2024/x/filter/less
:) helpers.c exists
Log
checking that helpers.c exists...
:) filter compiles
Log
running make...
checking that program exited with status 0...
:) grayscale correctly filters single pixel with whole number average
Log
testing with pixel (20, 40, 90)
running ./testing 0 0...
checking for output "50 50 50\n"...
:) grayscale correctly filters single pixel without whole number average
Log
testing with pixel (27, 28, 28)
running ./testing 0 1...
checking for output "28 28 28\n"...
:) grayscale leaves alone pixels that are already gray
Log
testing with pixel (50, 50, 50)
running ./testing 0 2...
checking for output "50 50 50\n"...
:) grayscale correctly filters simple 3x3 image
Log
testing with sample 3x3 image
first row: (255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0)
second row: (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0)
third row: (0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 255)
running ./testing 0 3...
checking for output "85 85 85\n85 85 85\n85 85 85\n85 85 85\n85 85 85\n85 85 85\n85 85 85\n85 85 85\n85 85 85\n"...
:) grayscale correctly filters more complex 3x3 image
Log
testing with sample 3x3 image
first row: (10, 20, 30), (40, 50, 60), (70, 80, 90)
second row: (110, 130, 140), (120, 140, 150), (130, 150, 160)
third row: (200, 210, 220), (220, 230, 240), (240, 250, 255)
running ./testing 0 4...
checking for output "20 20 20\n50 50 50\n80 80 80\n127 127 127\n137 137 137\n147 147 147\n210 210 210\n230 230 230\n248 248 248\n"...
:) grayscale correctly filters 4x4 image
Log
testing with sample 4x4 image
first row: (10, 20, 30), (40, 50, 60), (70, 80, 90), (100, 110, 120)
second row: (110, 130, 140), (120, 140, 150), (130, 150, 160), (140, 160, 170)
third row: (195, 204, 213), (205, 214, 223), (225, 234, 243), (245, 254, 253)
fourth row: (50, 28, 90), (0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255), (85, 85, 85)
running ./testing 0 5...
checking for output "20 20 20\n50 50 50\n80 80 80\n110 110 110\n127 127 127\n137 137 137\n147 147 147\n157 157 157\n204 204 204\n214 214 214\n234 234 234\n251 251 251\n56 56 56\n0 0 0\n255 255 255\n85 85 85\n"...
:) sepia correctly filters single pixel
Log
testing with pixel (20, 40, 90)
running ./testing 1 0...
checking for output "56 50 39\n"...
:) sepia correctly filters simple 3x3 image
Log
testing with sample 3x3 image
first row: (255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0)
second row: (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0)
third row: (0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 255)
running ./testing 1 3...
checking for output "100 89 69\n100 89 69\n100 89 69\n196 175 136\n196 175 136\n196 175 136\n48 43 33\n48 43 33\n48 43 33\n"...
:) sepia correctly filters more complex 3x3 image
Log
testing with sample 3x3 image
first row: (10, 20, 30), (40, 50, 60), (70, 80, 90)
second row: (110, 130, 140), (120, 140, 150), (130, 150, 160)
third row: (200, 210, 220), (220, 230, 240), (240, 250, 255)
running ./testing 1 4...
checking for output "25 22 17\n66 58 45\n106 94 74\n170 151 118\n183 163 127\n197 175 136\n255 251 195\n255 255 214\n255 255 232\n"...
:) sepia correctly filters 4x4 image
Log
testing with sample 4x4 image
first row: (10, 20, 30), (40, 50, 60), (70, 80, 90), (100, 110, 120)
second row: (110, 130, 140), (120, 140, 150), (130, 150, 160), (140, 160, 170)
third row: (195, 204, 213), (205, 214, 223), (225, 234, 243), (245, 254, 253)
fourth row: (50, 28, 90), (0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255), (85, 85, 85)
running ./testing 1 5...
checking for output "25 22 17\n66 58 45\n106 94 74\n147 131 102\n170 151 118\n183 163 127\n197 175 136\n210 187 146\n255 244 190\n255 255 199\n255 255 218\n255 255 235\n58 52 40\n0 0 0\n255 255 239\n115 102 80\n"...
:( reflect correctly filters 1x2 image
Cause
expected "0 0 255\n255 0...", not "0 0 0\n0 0 255..."
Log
testing with sample 1x2 image
first row: (255, 0, 0), (0, 0, 255)
running ./testing 2 0...
checking for output "0 0 255\n255 0 0\n"...

Expected Output:
0 0 255
255 0 0
Actual Output:
0 0 0
0 0 255
:( reflect correctly filters 1x3 image
Cause
expected "0 0 255\n0 255...", not "0 0 0\n0 0 255..."
Log
testing with sample 1x3 image
first row: (255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 0, 255)
running ./testing 2 1...
checking for output "0 0 255\n0 255 0\n255 0 0\n"...

Expected Output:
0 0 255
0 255 0
255 0 0
Actual Output:
0 0 0
0 0 255
0 0 255
:( reflect correctly filters image that is its own mirror image
Cause
expected "255 0 0\n255 0...", not "0 255 0\n255 0..."
Log
testing with sample 3x3 image
first row: (255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0)
second row: (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0), (0, 255, 0)
third row: (0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 255), (0, 0, 255)
running ./testing 2 2...
checking for output "255 0 0\n255 0 0\n255 0 0\n0 255 0\n0 255 0\n0 255 0\n0 0 255\n0 0 255\n0 0 255\n"...

Expected Output:
255 0 0
255 0 0
255 0 0
0 255 0
0 255 0
0 255 0
0 0 255
0 0 255
0 0 255
Actual Output:
0 255 0
255 0 0
255 0 0
0 0 255
0 255 0
0 255 0
0 0 0
0 0 255
0 0 255
:( reflect correctly filters 3x3 image
Cause
expected "70 80 90\n40 5...", not "110 130 140\n7..."
Log
testing with sample 3x3 image
first row: (10, 20, 30), (40, 50, 60), (70, 80, 90)
second row: (110, 130, 140), (120, 140, 150), (130, 150, 160)
third row: (200, 210, 220), (220, 230, 240), (240, 250, 255)
running ./testing 2 3...
checking for output "70 80 90\n40 50 60\n10 20 30\n130 150 160\n120 140 150\n110 130 140\n240 250 255\n220 230 240\n200 210 220\n"...

Expected Output:
70 80 90
40 50 60
10 20 30
130 150 160
120 140 150
110 130 140
240 250 255
220 230 240
200 210 220
Actual Output:
110 130 140
70 80 90
70 80 90
200 210 220
130 150 160
130 150 160
0 0 0
240 250 255
240 250 255
:( reflect correctly filters 4x4 image
Cause
expected "100 110 120\n7...", not "110 130 140\n1..."
Log
testing with sample 4x4 image
first row: (10, 20, 30), (40, 50, 60), (70, 80, 90), (100, 110, 120)
second row: (110, 130, 140), (120, 140, 150), (130, 150, 160), (140, 160, 170)
third row: (195, 204, 213), (205, 214, 223), (225, 234, 243), (245, 254, 253)
fourth row: (50, 28, 90), (0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255), (85, 85, 85)
running ./testing 2 4...
checking for output "100 110 120\n70 80 90\n40 50 60\n10 20 30\n140 160 170\n130 150 160\n120 140 150\n110 130 140\n245 254 253\n225 234 243\n205 214 223\n195 204 213\n85 85 85\n255 255 255\n0 0 0\n50 28 90\n"...

Expected Output:
100 110 120
70 80 90
40 50 60
10 20 30
140 160 170
130 150 160
120 140 150
110 130 140
245 254 253
225 234 243
205 214 223
195 204 213
85 85 85
255 255 255
0 0 0
50 28 90
Actual Output:
110 130 140
100 110 120
70 80 90
100 110 120
195 204 213
140 160 170
130 150 160
140 160 170
50 28 90
245 254 253
225 234 243
245 254 253
0 0 0
85 85 85
255 255 255
85 85 85
:( blur correctly filters middle pixel
Cause
expected "127 140 149\n", not "126 140 149\n"
Log
testing with sample 3x3 image
first row: (10, 20, 30), (40, 50, 60), (70, 80, 90)
second row: (110, 130, 140), (120, 140, 150), (130, 150, 160)
third row: (200, 210, 220), (220, 230, 240), (240, 250, 255)
running ./testing 3 0...
checking for output "127 140 149\n"...

Expected Output:
127 140 149
Actual Output:
126 140 149
:( blur correctly filters pixel on edge
Cause
expected "80 95 105\n", not "53 63 70\n"
Log
testing with sample 3x3 image
first row: (10, 20, 30), (40, 50, 60), (70, 80, 90)
second row: (110, 130, 140), (120, 140, 150), (130, 150, 160)
third row: (200, 210, 220), (220, 230, 240), (240, 250, 255)
running ./testing 3 1...
checking for output "80 95 105\n"...

Expected Output:
80 95 105
Actual Output:
53 63 70
:( blur correctly filters pixel in corner
Cause
expected "70 85 95\n", not "38 46 52\n"
Log
testing with sample 3x3 image
first row: (10, 20, 30), (40, 50, 60), (70, 80, 90)
second row: (110, 130, 140), (120, 140, 150), (130, 150, 160)
third row: (200, 210, 220), (220, 230, 240), (240, 250, 255)
running ./testing 3 2...
checking for output "70 85 95\n"...

Expected Output:
70 85 95
Actual Output:
38 46 52
:( blur correctly filters 3x3 image
Cause
expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "38 46 52\n53 6..."
Log
testing with sample 3x3 image
first row: (10, 20, 30), (40, 50, 60), (70, 80, 90)
second row: (110, 130, 140), (120, 140, 150), (130, 150, 160)
third row: (200, 210, 220), (220, 230, 240), (240, 250, 255)
running ./testing 3 3...
checking for output "70 85 95\n80 95 105\n90 105 115\n117 130 140\n127 140 149\n137 150 159\n163 178 188\n170 185 194\n178 193 201\n"...

Expected Output:
70 85 95
80 95 105
90 105 115
117 130 140
127 140 149
137 150 159
163 178 188
170 185 194
178 193 201
Actual Output:
38 46 52
53 63 70
75 86 94
100 112 121
126 140 149
125 137 146
121 132 139
113 123 129
101 108 113
:( blur correctly filters 4x4 image
Cause
expected "70 85 95\n80 9...", not "42 50 55\n53 6..."
Log
testing with sample 4x4 image
first row: (10, 20, 30), (40, 50, 60), (70, 80, 90), (100, 110, 120)
second row: (110, 130, 140), (120, 140, 150), (130, 150, 160), (140, 160, 170)
third row: (195, 204, 213), (205, 214, 223), (225, 234, 243), (245, 254, 253)
fourth row: (50, 28, 90), (0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255), (85, 85, 85)
running ./testing 3 4...
checking for output "70 85 95\n80 95 105\n100 115 125\n110 125 135\n113 126 136\n123 136 145\n142 155 163\n152 165 173\n113 119 136\n143 151 164\n156 166 171\n180 190 194\n113 112 132\n155 156 171\n169 174 177\n203 207 209\n"...

Expected Output:
70 85 95
80 95 105
100 115 125
110 125 135
113 126 136
123 136 145
142 155 163
152 165 173
113 119 136
143 151 164
156 166 171
180 190 194
113 112 132
155 156 171
169 174 177
203 207 209
Actual Output:
42 50 55
53 63 70
66 76 83
83 94 102
102 114 122
122 135 145
141 154 163
140 150 164
129 137 151
143 150 163
156 165 171
147 152 163
102 105 114
103 103 113
113 115 117
96 95 102

the grayscale and sepia functions seem to be working according to the cs50 check50 but the reflect and blur does not work
stack overflow is asking me to add more details can anyone advise me on what more i should add

I would advise trimming the check50 output to only the error cases and focusing on one issue at a time, either blur or reflect but not both. You can always ask another question for the other one. Trim the code to a single hardcoded issue. Explain the problem you're trying to solve. I know what blur is but not reflect. Many folks won't know what either of them are. You might also take a look at https://cs50.stackexchange.com/ for a more cs50 focused site.

In blur() you didn't round the averaged pixel colour components. Just image[i][j].rgbtRed = totalRed / count; etc.

In reflect() the indexing is off-by-one: [width-j] should be [width-1-j]. And what's this j < floor(width / 2) + 1; ? Shouldn't that be j < width / 2; ? No need to add 1 either – a central pixel won't need to be swapped.
